# Primefaces Mobile 5.0+ changing style of <p:tab> in <p:accordion>

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, mobile, primefaces

I am trying to change the style of `<p:tab>` in this way:

```
<p:ajax .../>
<p:tab id="tab1" title="Title"
       titleStyle="#{tabBackingMobile.tab1Changed ? 'background:red;' : ''}">
```

This works ONLY on Desktop version - in Mobile does NOT.
Does anyone know how to resolve his problem on Primefaces Mobile? I tried to use `titleStyleClass` using CSS class, but unfortunately nothing changes

For any help and tip thanks a lot! :)